# Internet gateway device protocol support?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, nat, upnp

As far as I understand, applications that need to transfer data across network address translators in a peer to peer fashion, like BitTorrent, usually rely on the UPNP IGD protocol to ask the router to temporarily map an external (UDP or TCP) port to an internal port, so that incoming connections can be accepted. I am developing a peer to peer application, and I based it entirely on UDP hole punching techniques. They work fine, but under certain circumstances I find it very difficult to establish a connection with non invasive methods, so I was considering the idea to make use of UPNP IGD, and only use hole punching when UPNP fails. However, since it doesn't look like such a trivial task, I wanted to get an idea if it is going to be worth the effort. How many NAT routers, in a standard internet home connection, accept UPNP IGD requests without having to configure portmapping manually? I would like my program to just work out of the box without having to configure anything manually on the router side.

As far as my understanding goes, this question can be split in two chunks:

How many home routers support UPNP? Like wifi home routers?
How many service providers NAT routers support UPNP?
That is, if I have, say, a standard internet connection with my home wifi, and my wifi router is given a private IP by my internet provider, what are my chances to actually make it to map a port from the public internet to my computer just with UPNP?

Comment: As far as I know (I may be wrong) most home routers do support UPNP. Whether they are on by default is a different matter, and lots of people who wants more control over their router do turn them off to avoid UPNP requests to open unwanted ports. If your ISP uses [Carrier Grade NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) so you ends up with some private non-routable IP address, your UPNP won't work at all as it will only open ports on your router, and your router IP is not accessible outside your ISP. It will work for connection inside the same ISP.

Comment: Oh. That's disappointing indeed. This means that there is no way at all to map an external port to an internal ip? Upnp doesn't sound so useful, if all it does is to let me connect with computers that are somehow local nonetheless..

Comment: Sorry I probably need to make myself clearer. UPNP will configure your router to accept incoming connection at certain ports (as required and configured by UPNP) from your router end. In most cases (where ISP assigns you publicly routable IP address), your router can be directly connected by outside forces, and the pre-configured port by UPNP will work perfectly. In your case (since you mention about private IP by ISP - I'm assuming you are talking about Carrier-Grade NAT) then you do NOT have publicly accessible IP address and UPNP will means little/nothing.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to know, thank you. The only thing I don't quite understand is when you say that in most cases my  ISP will assign a public ip to my connection. As far as my understanding goes, that is indeed a tiny minority of the cases... I mean: I thought that most of ISPs nowadays make use of carrier grade NATs...

Comment: Maybe. This I can't confirm. In Australia we still have public IP so we can connect back to our home connection. The fact that IPv4 are running out do means that ISP will either move to IPv6 or use CGN as they will run out the allocated IP set that they have. So each country experience will vary.